# Do "let" and "const" work in Adobe scripts?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting, script

Do they work or they don't? Changing some `var` variables to `let` resulted into error, while changing some of them to `const` didn't. Are both of them unsupported?

Answer (score 1):

[Not currently](https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator-discussions/what-version-of-javascript-supported/td-p/10488199).

> I was just curious what version of JS does ESTK support for Adobe Illustrator? I am noticing that “const” works, but “let” does not. Is there a list somewhere of supported language features?
>
> - [mickyhulse](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/7124461), Jun 19, 2019

> ExtendScript based ECMA Edition 3 and not support "let" and "const" is better not to use it.
>
> - [Ten A](https://community.adobe.com/t5/user/viewprofilepage/user-id/9510373) (Adobe Community Professional), Jun 20, 2019

---

Interestingly, it appears that [After Effects supports most of ECMA 2018](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/legacy-and-extend-script-engine.html#ECMAScript) which would include `let` and `const`.

The Illustrator user guide [doesn't have much to say](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/automation-scripts.html) but there's [a bug report](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/601447-illustrator-desktop-bugs/suggestions/39782218--let-declarations-not-supported-in-jsx-files) that has been inactive since Feb 24, 2020.